# Как передать массив post запросом с формы?

Tags: массивы, post, javascript, форма

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста что нужно прописать в функции add что-бы передать массив данных test?

Форма:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="add();return false;">
    Тест поле1: <input type="text" value="..." name="test[name]" /><br/>
    Тест поле2: <input type="text" value="5" name="test[price]" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
</form>
```

Comment: @infolabs, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я нечего не сделал, так как не понимаю как передать test в функцию. Вот и спрашиваю. И какое учебное задание, с чего вы взяли что я как то отношусь к учреждению образования?

Comment: Синхронно или асинхронно?

Comment: Лучше конечно асинхронно. Но это не принципиально.

Comment: про jquery слышали? это самый простой прособ.

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Конкретнее напишите

Answer (score 1):

Нужно подключить jquery, в форме вместо submit указать:
< input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Добавить" />

В файле js

```
function add() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: {"name":name ,"price":price},
        url:"script.php",
        success:function(html){
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

И в script.php надо не забыть проверить сессию и куки, чтобы никто не добавил данные обратившись напрямую к этому скрипту.

Comment: **никогда** не используйте onclick в разметке html с jquery. тем более что для форм надо использовать submit а не click.

Comment: "никогда не используйте onclick в разметке html с jquery"
Почему?

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли вопрос. Вопрос был совсем в другом. По отдельности я прекрастно знаю как передавать данные

Comment: @Zepp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick

к сказанному в ссылке могу добавить, что таким образом вы еще и вынуждены засорять глобальное scope  функциями, которым в глобале делать нечего.